# is_deleted for nodes with Django MPTT

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-mptt

I use Django MPTT.

I wont delete my nodes but instead I am updating a field `is_deleted` and filtering the nodes so 'deleted' nodes wont show up.

The problem arises if a node is 'deleted' but some of it's descendants is not deleted.

The descendants of a 'deleted' node should not be showed. I could solve this by setting the `is_deleted` field for all descendants when I 'delete' a node but that is not the best solution.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Simply set **is_deleted** to first level (root) objects `some_object.get_root()`, then get descendances of all objects in this queryset  `SomeModel.objects.filter(level=0).exclude(is_deleted=True)` [django-mptt get_descendants for a list of nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722767/django-mptt-get-descendants-for-a-list-of-nodes)

Comment: I am not interested in setting `is_deleted` for only the root node. Sometimes it's the root node which I am going to delete but other times it's nodes on other levels.

Comment: Then set `is_deleted=True` to deleted objects, then `black_list = get_queryset_descendants(SomeModel.objects.filter(is_deleted=True), include_self=True)` you will have list of deleted objects with their descendants, Finally you have to exclude them all `SomeModel.objects.exclude(pk__in=[o.id for o in black_list])`